# QT Release missing MSVC Debug dependencies

Tags: qt, visual-c++

I have two libraries compiled on **VS 2015**. Both libraries are configured to Release and I am using **/MT** for C++ code generation.
I am linking these libraries to a QT application and everything is working fine. Also my QT configuration is set to `Release`.

When I try to use the release folder on another PC that doesn't have Visual Studio installed on it I get dependency errors:

Missing `MSVCP140D.DLL`, `VCRUNTIME140D.DLL`, and `ucrtbased.dll`

I tried installing **MSVC 2015 redistributable** on the target PC but nothing changed. Is it something that I am missing that need these debug DLLs?

Comment: The error indicates that one of the libraries (or a dependency of a library) is a debug build that references those debug DLLs. Recheck the build logfiles (like `link.read.1.tlog`) to figure out which one, or use [Dependency Walker](https://www.dependencywalker.com/) to check the libraries directly (outdated, but will still show the basic information).